# Delaminating in the middle area of photon printer

Tags: resin, uv-printer, delamination

I've been getting delaminating and other issues in the middle area of my Anycubic photon printer.

Sometimes the print won't stick to the print bed and sometimes it delaminates like in the images below, but I'm only seeing issues in the middle of the printer. Anything along the edges of the print area prints without issue.

- I've tested the screen, it seems to work. No dead areas.
- I've tried multiple different prints (I only have issues in the middle area).
- The problem usually is early in the print but the size of the print does not seem to matter.
- The print bed does not appear to be warped.
- FEP tensioned using the Tuning method.

[image: Print on print bed]

The prints can be seen attracted to the print bed here. The part of it that is facing each other is where there were issues.

[image: Delamation example]

Delamation example (both prints had the same issues)

[image: CAD image]

Settings used:

- **Resin:** Elegoo ABS-Like Grey
- **Layer thickness:** 50 µm
- **Bottom layers exposure time:** 100 s
- **Number of bottom layers:** 10
- **Normal layer exposure time:** 11 s

Comment: Should the title *really* say "in the middle" twice? I've removed the duplicate "in the middle". If that was wrong, please feel free to rollback to edit #2

Answer (score 1):

The print you do is a sealed cup in the position it sits directly on the build plate. As a result, [there is a column of resin in the cup](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/why-is-cupping-bad-in-sla-prints) as you print and at some point, the weakest spot delaminates, the air gets into the column and drains.

Take the print and either angle it by a few degrees so the hole in the top becomes a vent or add a tiny extra vent-hole.